# Acrobat Reader DC keeps asking for file location, how do I make it stop?

Tags: pdf, adobe-reader

When I want to save a modified PDF in Acrobat Reader DC instead of just saving the file Acrobat Reader opens the *Save As* dialog, where I have to pick a folder.
When annotating a large number of files this becomes really annoying.

Any hints?

Steps to reproduce:

- open PDF from Explorer
- highlight some word
- CTRL+S

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that this is related to the setting "Enable Projected Mode at Startup" in Edit > Preferences > Security (Enhanced). Disabling it will allow to just save a file with CTRL+S.

As pointed out in [this post on Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23977075/how-can-i-stop-adobe-reader-from-asking-save-as-when-saving-a-pdf-form-i-e-a).

Answer (score 0):

"(Windows) Explorer" gives a key.

Can we assume that the preview function of Windows Explorer is on?

If so, you also should get an according error message, stating that saving is not possible because the document is open by another application. And that other application is Windows Explorer when the preview function is on.

Deactivate that preview function, and you will be able to save the document.

Comment: That's not the problem. When the _Save As_ dialog comes up, I can select the folder where the .pdf is stored. Acrobat Reader will warn me that a file with the same name already exists (no surprise), but once I confirm, I can just save the file.

Answer (score -1):

Had the same problem and this fixed it!:

"It seems that this is related to the setting "Enable Projected Mode at Startup" in Edit > Preferences > Security (Enhanced). Disabling it will allow to just save a file with CTRL+S."

Thanks!

Comment: Please do not post "thank you" comments as answers. If you wish to comment, interact with SuperUser a bit and work up the reputation necessary to comment.